# Generate TLS certs for Elasticcluster with ansible

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, tty

During generating tls cert for Elastic cluster with `elasticsearch-certutil` tool i get:

`unable to read from standard input; is standard input open and a tty attached?`

I know that for installing installing plugins or generating password tools can used `force` and `batch` flags, but there are no for this one.

`ansible` task (part):

```
- name: Create certificates p12
  shell: |
    cd /usr/share/elasticsearch && \
    ./bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca -s --out elastic-stack-ca.p12 --pass {{ ca_password }} && \
    ./bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert -s --ca elastic-stack-ca.p12 --ca-pass {{ ca_password }} --out elastic-certificates.p12 --pass {{ cert_password }} && \
    cp elastic-certificates.p12 /etc/elasticsearch && \
    chmod 660 /etc/elasticsearch/elastic-certificates.p12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- name: Generate a certificate of authority
  args:
    chdir: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}'
  become: yes
  command: "{{ elastic_home }}/bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --out {{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass }}'"
- name: Generate a certificate and private key for a node
  args:
    chdir: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}'
  become: yes
  command: "{{ elastic_home }}/bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca {{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --ca-pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass }}' --out {{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/elastic-certificates.p12 --pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_ca_pass }}'"
- name: Change cert permissions
  file:
    path: "{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/elastic-certificates.p12"
    owner: root
    group: elasticsearch
    mode: '0666'
```

I simply split in it for 3 pars and it works